# Concurrent write-only transactions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The [datastore documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction) says that:

> Upon commiting a transaction for the entity groups, App Engine again
>   checks the last update time for the entity groups used in the
>   transaction. If it has changed since our initial check, App Engine
>   throws an exception

I have three test cases about performing a transacted datastore put of a `new Entity("TestEntity",1)` in two concurrent transactions.

- test1: put the entity in the first transaction, put the entity in the second transaction, and commit both transactions. This test passes (i.e. throws `ConcurrentModificationException`) when run in developement server and standalone unit tests, but fails (i.e. executes without throwing an exception) when run in production server.
- test2: put the entity in the first transaction and commit it, then put the entity in the second transaction and commit it. This test always fails.
- test3: attempt to get the (non-existing) entity in both transactions, then do test2. This test always passes by throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`.

From these tests I conclude that neither `beginTransaction` nor `put` guarantee that "*the initial check*" is performed, and I need to pay a *get* in order to guarantee the integrity of the transaction. Is that correct?

```
@Test(expected=ConcurrentModificationException.class)
//put1 put2 commit1 commit2
public void test1() {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Transaction txn1 = ds.beginTransaction();
    Transaction txn2 = ds.beginTransaction();
    ds.put(txn1,new Entity("TestEntity",1));
    ds.put(txn2,new Entity("TestEntity",1));
    txn1.commit();
    txn2.commit();
}

@Test(expected=ConcurrentModificationException.class)
//put1 commit1 put2 commit2
public void test2()  {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Transaction txn1 = ds.beginTransaction();
    Transaction txn2 = ds.beginTransaction();
    ds.put(txn1,new Entity("TestEntity",1));
    txn1.commit();
    ds.put(txn2,new Entity("TestEntity",1)); 
    txn2.commit(); 
}

@Test(expected=ConcurrentModificationException.class)
//get1 get2 put1 commit1 put2 commit2
public void test3() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    ds.delete(KeyFactory.createKey("TestEntity", 1));
    Transaction txn1 = ds.beginTransaction();
    Transaction txn2 = ds.beginTransaction();
    Assert.assertNull(getTestEntity(ds, txn1));
    Assert.assertNull(getTestEntity(ds, txn2));
    ds.put(txn1,new Entity("TestEntity",1));
    txn1.commit();
    ds.put(txn2,new Entity("TestEntity",1));
    txn2.commit();
}
```

Comment: For a minute I thought this question was going to be about a write only databases.... I've got a really performant one I was going to sell you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in a sense.  (MVCC) Consistency doesn't *require* a timestamp until the first event where the transaction observes a snapshot of mutable data.

Think about it: how could a transaction that mutated a single record without any reads violate consistency?  Since it issued no reads, it essentially makes no assumptions.  Therefore there are no assumptions that could be broken to result in a write-write conflict.

The bottom line is you're getting the safety benefits of consistency, no matter what.  Enforcing that consistency simply doesn't require a timestamp until you issue the first transactional read.